# Generate 128-bit md5 hash with base64 coding

Tags: java, hash, md5, encode, md5sum

I need to get a hash sum like this ODA1OTU0NDVkMzkwNTU5N2NlMmNiOTc0Nzk4ZGY2YjI= (44 symbols).

How can I get it correctly? These methods did not help me.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.reset();
md.update(part);    // part - array of bytes
byte[] digest = md.digest();
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(part);
String checksum = new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16);    // b8e82d4ff9aef02913b081930caa46f9
String myHashHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);// B8E82D4FF9AEF02913B081930CAA46F9
String myHash64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(digest); // RRbu8RMW/XSDBwNW9WWYhA==
String md5Str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest); // RRbu8RMW/XSDBwNW9WWYhA==
```

I wanted to get a hash sum like this ODA1OTU0NDVkMzkwNTU5N2NlMmNiOTc0Nzk4ZGY2YjI= but can't do it well. I expect for the right solution to my problem with Java.

Comment: The base64 encoding of your hash is `uOgtT/mu8CkTsIGTDKpG+Q==` *Hash sum* doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to produce?

Comment: A base64 encoding of a 128-bit hash (16 bytes) is 16 * 4 / 3 = 21 => 24 characters with padding, just like your current results. If you need to get a base64 string of 44 characters (44 / 4 * 3 = 33 => 31 - 33 bytes), so either you need to invent extra bytes , or the original encoding does something stupid like hex-encoding the hash (2 * 16 = 32), and then base64 encoding the hex-encoded string, arriving at a base64 encoded string of 44 characters. You need to ask the author of whatever requires this hash for the requirements/specification of the encoding.

Comment: Also, decoding `ODA1OTU0NDVkMzkwNTU5N2NlMmNiOTc0Nzk4ZGY2YjI=` gives `80595445d3905597ce2cb974798df6b2` (32 hex characters, representing 16 bytes), which seems to confirm that you need to use base64(hex(hash)) instead of just base64(hash).

Comment: *which seems to confirm that you need to use base64(hex(hash)) instead of just base64(hash)* Yes - except - of course rather pointless to base64-encode something that's already text, *and* expanding by 4/3 something that's *already* doubled in storage size ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for me base64(hex(hash))

Comment: The API has a terrible specification, but now it works for me base64(hex(hash)). Thanks a million guys!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me! Thanks a lot!

```
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(part);
String hexString = new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16); // 4516eef11316fd7483070356f5659884
String md5Str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hexString.getBytes()); // NDUxNkVFRjExMzE2RkQ3NDgzMDcwMzU2RjU2NTk4ODQ=
```

Comment: As an aside, Java 17 introduced `java.util.HexFormat`. I suggest using that instead of `BigInteger`.

Comment: That is cool but I work in a legacy project in Java 8 unfortunately :-)